# What exact settings required in iis for asp.net pages to process it faster?

Tags: iis-7

I am having a simple blank page without any source code.The page also taking very long time to come.I am not able to understand the reason behind this.
The domain is getting a high requests.

What exact settings needs to be done in iis 7.0 so that it will be faster.

Please help.

Comment: You need a better server machine.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET pages always have an initial delay when the first request is made after the file has been created/edited/uploaded because the server needs to recompile them, however it shouldn't be more than 2-3 seconds in practice, and does not affect subsequent pageloads.

The only thing I can think of is an overloaded server. Assuming you're on a shared hosting package then I recommend you find another ISP. If not, then I'm afraid there's a lot more to it than just a "page pages load faster" switch hidden away.